# Spaces inserted in concatenated strings despite use of braces

Tags: bash

I used the following syntax to read in a file name and modify its extensions to generate the name of a matched data file. As an example, I have ABC_1.fastq.Blockxy, XYZ_1.fastq.Block34 and I want to generate ABC_2.fastq.Block12, XYZ_2.fastq.Block34 as my new file name:

```
for infile in *_1.fastq.Block*
do
    #base=$(basename ${infile} _1.fastq.**)
    IFS='_'
    read -ra ADDR <<< $infile
    base=${ADDR[0]}
    IFS='.'
    read -ra ADDR <<< ${ADDR[1]}
    second_file="${base}_2.fastq.${ADDR[2]}"
    echo $second_file
done
```

When executed, this script prints e.g.

```
ABC_2 fastq Block12
XYZ_2 fastq Block34
```

i.e. spaces between fastq and Block12. Why am I getting spaces rather than a period between these three strings when I concatenate? I thought that using braces for variable names should have eliminated this problem.

Comment: Wouldn't `second_file="${infile/_1/_2}"` be a lot easier?

Comment: Yes, that works in this case. However, for more complicated examples I do want to be able to use pieces of the split string to create new strings. I still don't understand why I'm getting spaces and no periods between the string elements with second_file.

Comment: I take it it's because IFS is still set to ".", which is making `echo` treat the variable as multiple arguments rather than one. You can `unset IFS` prior to the echo or put in quotes, `echo "$second_file"`.

Answer (score 1):

In

> ```
> echo $second_file
> ```

Since you forgot to quote the parameter expansion, it's subject to split+glob, so with `IFS=.`, `ABC_2.fastq.Block12` is first split into, `ABC_2`, `fastq` and `Block12` and each word subject to globbing, with no effect here since none of the words contain glob operators.

So 3 arguments are passed to `echo` which it prints space separated.

To print the contents of a variable followed by a newline character, you need:

```
printf '%s\n' "$var"
```

For more details, see:

- [When is double-quoting necessary?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/68694)
- [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803)

---

Now, a few more comments on your code:

- since bash doesn't have the equivalent of `zsh`'s `(N)` glob qualifier or ksh93's `~(N)` glob operator, before using a glob in a for loop (at least), you need to set the `nullglob` option:

  ```
  shopt -s nullglob
  for infile in *_1.fastq.Block*; do...
  ```

  If you don't and there's no matching file, you'll loop over a literal `*_1.fastq.Block*`
- You can set IFS for `read` only with: `IFS=_ read -ra ADDR <<< "$infile"` (see also the quotes around `$infile`  which are needed in older versions of `bash`). That way, `$IFS` is only changed while `read` runs¹ and it's restored to its previous value after `read` returns.
- `IFS=. read -ra <<< "$var"` is a poor method for splitting. First is only works for single line `$var`s which is not necessarily the case of file names, and also it's quite inefficient. That involves either storing the contents of `$var` into a tempfile or feed it via a pipe depending on the version of `bash` and/or the size of `$var` and then reading it one byte at a time until a newline is found.

  Here, you could use the split+glob operator instead:

  ```
  IFS=:; set -o noglob
  addr=( $infile )
  ```

  (or `addr=( $infile'' )` to *not* ignore a trailing `:`.)

  Or switch to better shells with proper splitting operators.

  Another approach here would be to do:

  ```
  regex='^(.*)_1\.fastq\.(Block.*)$'
  if [[ $infile =~ $regex ]]; then
    outfile=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}_2.fastq.${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
    ...
  ```

  With the caveat that regex matching only works with valid text, which again is not a guarantee for file names.

  Here, you could also use standard `sh` parameter expansion operators:

  ```
  new_file=${infile%_1.fastq.Block*}_2.fastq.Block${infile##*_1.fastq.Block}
  ```

  Or the ksh93-style:

  ```
  new_file=${infile/_1.fastq.Block/_2.fastq.Block}
  ```

  (note the variations in behaviour among all those approaches if `_1.fastq.Block` occurs more than once in the file name).

---

<sup>¹ Though beware that if a `trap` is handled whilst `read` is running, the code in that trap will have the modified `$IFS`</sup>